# Parse seconds-of-day as part of a date string

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time, datetime-parsing

I need to parse a date string which has the following format:
`yyyy-MM-dd TTTTT`. All pattern letters are the standard [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) letters, except for the `TTTTT` part, which is a *seconds-of-day* field.

As there is no pattern defined for such a field, I needed to come up with something else. My first thought was to try and parse the field as *milli-of-day* (`A`), but by using 5 `A`'s my field is treated as the least significant characters which is... yeah, not what I want.

Is there any out-of-the box solution I could use or do I have to resort to some custom made solution (like ignoring the `TTTTT` field, parsing it manually and using `LocalDateTime.plusSeconds()` on the resulting date)?

In other words, how can I make the following test case pass?

```
public class DateTimeParserTest {
    private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd TTTTT";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN);

    @Test
    public void testParseSecondsOfDay() throws Exception {
        String input = "2016-01-01 86399";
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, FORMATTER);
        assertEquals("2016-01-01T23:59:59", localDateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: 86399 as second-of-day corresponds to clock time 23:59:59, not to 00:00 so your input contains two different times. How do you want to resolve this ambivalence? The part "00:00:86399" is simply not valid. Therefore the solution `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:").appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 5).toFormatter();` will not help.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild you are totally right, I corrected the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your correction (leaving out the potentially ambivalent part "HH:mm") the Java-8-solution would look like:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd ")
  .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 5)
  .toFormatter();
```

Comment: Spot on! I prefer [appending a whitespace character explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendLiteral-char-) but it's purely a matter of taste. While some people like to type less, someone like me prefers more readability, even at the cost of more typing.

Answer (score 0):

well it may not be what what you are looking, but i hope it helps

```
    private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; //MODIFICATION HERE 
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN);

    @Test
    public void testParseSecondsOfDay() throws Exception {
        String input = "2016-01-01 00:00:86399";

        int lastIndexOf = input.lastIndexOf(':');
        CharSequence parsable = input.subSequence(0,lastIndexOf)+":00";
        CharSequence TTTTPart = input.subSequence(lastIndexOf+1, input.length());


        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(parsable, FORMATTER);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale.
        calendar.set(
                localDateTime.getYear(), 
                localDateTime.getMonth().ordinal(),
                localDateTime.getDayOfMonth(),
                localDateTime.getHour(),
                localDateTime.getMinute(),
                0);

        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(TTTTPart.toString()));

        StringBuilder toParse = new StringBuilder();
        toParse.append(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) /* It gives 2016 but you what 2016, why */-1);
        toParse.append("-").append(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 < 10 ? "0" : "")
            .append(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
        toParse.append("-").append(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 10 ? "0" : "")
            .append(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        toParse.append(" ").append(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 10 ? "0" : "")
            .append(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        toParse.append(":").append(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 10 ? "0" : "")
            .append(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        toParse.append(":").append(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) < 10 ? "0" : "")
            .append(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

        localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(toParse, FORMATTER);

        //Why 2015 and not 2016?
        assertEquals("2015-01-01T23:59:59", localDateTime.toString());

    }
```

it bugs me with is 2015 and not 2016, be aware that the solution is hammered to give you 2015 instead of 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using Joda and no java8, but there it would be

```
    Chronology lenient = LenientChronology.getInstance(ISOChronology.getInstance());

    DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sssss").withChronology(lenient);
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("2016-01-01 00:00:86399", FORMATTER);
    assertEquals("2016-01-01T23:59:59", dateTime.toLocalDateTime().toString());
```

Maybe you can obtain the same behavior using:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
         DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
```

Comment: There is no pattern symbol for second-of-day ("s" is second-of-minute). And lenient handling of ambivalent informations is surely not good.